# Cannot infer functional interface with HashMap computeIfAbsent

Tags: java

I have a HashMap defined as

```java
final Map<String, List<Tuple<ShipmentDTO, ShipmentItemDTO>>> itemMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Java is quite happy with

```java
itemMap.put("id", new ArrayList<>());
```

But fails with "Cannot infer functional interface type" with

```java
itemMap.computeIfAbsent("id", () -> new ArrayList<>());
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: `itemMap.computeIfAbsent("id", key -> new ArrayList<>());` – The second argument is a `Function`, meaning it takes an argument.

Comment: I googled many things, read many other SO articles about "Cannot infer functional interface type", tried many other syntax variants and studied the compiler error very carefully, but none of these led me to the solution.
I always spend a lot of effort to try to fix issues before posting on SO, then i know that having this question answered on SO will save someone else effort in the future because the answer is not obvious.
My code would work as written in C# - which I am much more familiar with.

Comment: May I ask what version of Java are you using? On Java 20, if I try to compile your code I get `incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression`, which is much more clear.

Comment: As an aside, it looks like Java 21 [will let you use `_` for unused params as a preview feature](https://openjdk.org/jeps/443) (though you would still need to do `_ -> new ArrayList<>()`, not just `() -> new ArrayList<>()`).

Comment: This project is Java 17, but we have projects on all versions from 1.8 to 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `computeIfAbsent` method takes a `key` and function interface `Function<T, R>` as parameters.

Function interface `Function<T, R>` represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

**T**: *Type of argument.*

**R**: *Return type of the function.*

The problem is you have not supplied an arugment. So, it is giving compilation error.

You need to change it to:

```
itemMap.computeIfAbsent("id", (s) -> new ArrayList<>());
```

where `s` is the key.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I read the compiler error multiple times, and it did not help at all!